# Angular - how to read file names in a directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modx

I'm using Angular JS in a ModX app, and I need to read the file names in a gallery (ModX's Gallery pacakge) every time the gallery is updated. Is there a way to do this in Angular?

I tried researching Javascript solutions to this problem, but all I saw were solutions using ActiveX, and this needs to be cross-browser compatible.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to leave that up to the backend and just give the information to Angular

Comment: @Strawberry Then is there a way (a service, e.g.) to add file names in a directory to a $scope var?

Comment: Ideally, you would just want your ModX app to give you a JSON of filenames, and then you can do anything with Angular from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Strawberry is correct, this is a backend function. What you'll want to do is to set up a service on your backend that returns either json (simpler) or xml and then use either angular's $http or $resource service to make a call to that backend service. Review the $http doc on angular site for more details.

Comment: @Dan_Doyon I would like to do it this way, but the images in the gallery will be changed by the client, so I need to scan the directory for new/deleted images each time.

Comment: If I'm understanding problem correctly, in order for browser to be able to access the client's computer you need elevated permissions, which something like ActiveX affords you. Is this an internet or extranet app?

Comment: It's internet based, so it will have to be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Presuming that the images are sent to serverside, you could just poll server for changes by calling your shiny new "PhotoGallery" http service using angular's $timeout service with a reasonable interval. We've written a monitoring service in angular that monitors data state and it works quite nicely. I don't know anything about ModX so I hope I'm steering you in right direction. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Dan and Strawberry. Your advice pointed me in the right direction. I ended up spitting out the gallery's file names into javascript with ModX's [[Gallery]] tags, then grabbed them in Angular and created a custom service to massage the data and send it back to the views.